# Issues when requesting FTP file with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ftp

I am trying to make a part in my routine which retrieves a .xls document from a FTP location.

I have been googling for quite a few hours now and I am starting to get quite frustrated with this piece of code.

When running the code I get Run-Time error '3001' saying that my arguments are either of the wrong type and are out of the aceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

```
Sub GetFTPFile()
    Dim objXML
    Dim strFTPResponse
    Dim varUser, varPassword As Variant
    Dim LocalDir As String

    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    strURL = "ftp://xyz_hourly.xls"
    LocalDir = "c//"
    varUser = "xxx"
    varPassword = "yyy"

    Call objXML.Open("GET", strURL, varUser, varPassword, False)
    Call objXML.send

    Do While objXML.readystate <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set File = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    File.Type = 1
    File.Open
    File.Write objXML.ResponseBody
    File.SaveToFile "c//yyy.xlsx", 2
End Sub
```

Comment: See my post on downloading files using VBA here: http://www.analystcave.com/excel-downloading-files-using-vba/

Comment: See page 2 of my post with the `DownloadBinaryFile` procedure. Just tested it on an `ftp` link and it works.